# How to make a modified or custom android SDK to build apps for a custom Android ROM?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I have a custom Android ROM, the problem is that I modified some JAVA API classes but android studio uses the google SDK, so I can't develop apps using the new features in my ROM because android studio don't recognize my methods or attributes, and I would like to know if it is posibble to obtain a custom SDK to use in android studio and how. Somebody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[a tutoial on how to build Android SDK](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt) but you have to build an ADT for Eclipse not Android Studio.

Comment: It seems that the tutorial, first explain how to make the SDK and then how to make the ADT for Eclipse, it  could be usefull for me because once I have the SDK I can configure Android Studio where the SDK is. I will try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot androidLover. (Y)